# How to bind angular2 data with the service in mvc6

Tags: angular2-services

I am new to angular2. I prepared my UI using angular2 having some dropdown list and textboxes. Now I need to Send these data(object) to the service to store permanently.How to do that in MVC6. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the total process if getting data from angular and save it in the database using MVC. The total process cannot be explained here, but you can watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2xPKz3Uqu4) to get a basic understanding of achieving your requirement. If you have some specific code related issue then you can ask again here.

Answer (score 0):

## STEPS TO CREATE ANGULAR2 App and consume MVC6 services.

This is a kind of whole development process in which we you need to define MVC6 services first and after that you need to create a angular2 app using [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) (which is in beta version). It is very very helpful...

You can follow some steps and you able to get what you wanted to done with angular2 and MVC6 services.

1. Create services api end points.
2. Create a angular2 app
3. Create [angular2 service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html).
4. Create [angular2 component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).
5. Inject [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) and consume in [component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html).
6. Now you able to consume your MVC6 services in angular2 app through [angular2 service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html).

#### Wish this will help you.